# Telerik Silverlight RadTreeview AutoRefresh

Tags: silverlight, treeview, telerik

In my application I am using the Telerik Silverlight RadTreeView control. This is populated with hierarchical, load on demand data.

My view refreshes every 60 seconds and I want to maintain the expanded nodes, the selected item and the scroll postion.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks,
Mark

Comment: @Mark: Its bizare someone seems to have taken disliking all recent silverlight questions and downvoted them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good suggestion from Telerik is to add [ContainerBindings along with your HierarchicalData](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/silverlight/treeview/radtreeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx)

I think this needs a little polishing - maybe extension methods or some inheritance, but is pretty much the right way to go.